# Audio data string format to numpy array

Tags: python, string, numpy, audio, format-conversion

I am trying to convert audio sample rate (from 44100 to 22050) of a numpy.array with 88200 samples in which I have already done some process (such as add silence and convert to mono). I tried to convert this array with `audioop.ratecv` and it work, but it return a str instead of a numpy array and when I wrote those data with `scipy.io.wavfile.write` the result was half of the data are lost and the audio speed is twice as fast (instead of slower, at least that would make kinda sense). 
`audio.ratecv` works fine with str arrays such as `wave.open` returns, but I don't know how to process those, so I tried to convert from str to numpy with `numpy.array2string(data)` to pass this on ratecv and get correct results, and then convert again to numpy with `numpy.fromstring(data, dtype)` and now len of data is 8 samples. I think this is due to complication of formats, but I don't know how can I control it. I also haven't figure out what kind of format str does `wave.open` returns so I can force format on this one.

Here is this part of my code

```
def conv_sr(data, srold, fixSR, dType, chan = 1): 
    state = None
    width = 2 # numpy.int16
    print "data shape", data.shape, type(data[0]) # returns shape 88200, type int16
    fragments = numpy.array2string(data)
    print "new fragments len", len(fragments), "type", type(fragments) # return len 30 type str
    fragments_new, state = audioop.ratecv(fragments, width, chan, srold, fixSR, state)
    print "fragments", len(fragments_new), type(fragments_new[0]) # returns 16, type str
    data_to_return = numpy.fromstring(fragments_new, dtype=dType)
    return data_to_return
```

and I call it like this

```
data1 = numpy.array(data1, dtype=dType)
data_to_copy = numpy.append(data1, data2)
data_to_copy = _to_copy.sum(axis = 1) / chan
data_to_copy = data_to_copy.flatten() # because its mono

data_to_copy = conv_sr(data_to_copy, sr, fixSR, dType) #sr = 44100, fixSR = 22050

scipy.io.wavfile.write(filename, fixSR, data_to_copy)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more of research I found my mistake, it seems that 16 bit audio are made of two 8 bit 'cells', so the dtype I was putting on was false and that's why I had audio speed issue. I found the correct dtype [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype). So, in conv_sr def, I am passing a numpy array, convert it to data string, pass it to convert sample rate, converting again to numpy array for `scipy.io.wavfile.write` and finally, converting 2 8bits to 16 bit format

```
def widthFinder(dType):
    try:
        b = str(dType)
        bits = int(b[-2:])
    except:
        b = str(dType)
        bits = int(b[-1:])
    width = bits/8
    return width

def conv_sr(data, srold, fixSR, dType, chan = 1): 
    state = None
    width = widthFinder(dType)
    if width != 1 and width != 2 and width != 4:
        width = 2
    fragments = data.tobytes()
    fragments_new, state = audioop.ratecv(fragments, width, chan, srold, fixSR, state)
    fragments_dtype = numpy.dtype((numpy.int16, {'x':(numpy.int8,0), 'y':(numpy.int8,1)}))
    data_to_return = numpy.fromstring(fragments_new, dtype=fragments_dtype)
    data_to_return = data_to_return.astype(dType)
    return data_to_return
```

If you find anything wrong, please feel free to correct me, I am still a learner